# Inserting a column at the end in a database diagram and repositioning existing columns

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I like working on my schema directly within a database diagram.  From there, you can set table properties, column properties, add columns, remove, etc. (in addition to, of course, being able to easily define relationships).

However, it doesn't seem to be possible to insert a column at the end of a table's columns or to reposition existing columns.  I can insert a column by selecting an existing column and right-clicking > "Insert Column", but that column always appears above the selected column.  When I do this and create the column, I cannot drag it to reposition the column despite the drag cursor appearing.

Is there a workaround?

[image]

Comment: You should see an empty line at the end of the list of columns. You can append a new column just typing in that empty line....

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti -- That's not correct.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti -- See Steve's answer.  Maybe you already have Table View set to "Standard"?  See my screen shot for comparison.

Comment: Why are you designing tables in a database diagram in the first place? The best way to design your tables is with ddl and not visual tools.

Comment: @SeanLange -- Why do you say that?

Comment: Have you seen the code generated from visual tools? If you write the ddl yourself you have a lot more control over your tables. It may be a little slower at first but once you learn the syntax it is much faster too.

Comment: The bigger question is why do you care what the order of the columns is? You should always reference columns by name so the storage order shouldn't make any real difference.

Comment: @SeanLange -- I haven't seen the code generated from visual tools, but what does it matter what code they generate.  In my opinion, it's quicker and easier to do it that way.  And as for column order, -- yeah, I've heard that one before.  I'm not going to get into why column order matters to me, but there are plenty of reasons.  This isn't my first rodeo; I've been coding professionally for over a decade, and seeking out and using best practices is my M.O.  But that doesn't mean that I blindly follow the "words of wisdom" from other people either.

Comment: I always reference columns by name.  But column order still matters to me.

Comment: I never suggested this was your first rodeo but glad you could get defensive about it. We will have to agree to disagree about how to create tables. I would argue that using the visual designer for your tables contradicts your statement that your M.O. is to seek out and use best practices. If the tables are empty moving columns around is not a big deal, but when they are full it can take a really long time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to use database diagrams too. If you right click on the header of the table and select Table View -> Standard you will be presented with an editable grid which allows you to add a column to the end of the table.

I should also say that you can also use Table View -> Modify Custom to allow you to modify all attributes of a column such identity etc. Once you have done this you can use Table View -> Custom to be able to update these.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I set the table view to "Standard", but I still cannot add a column to the end of the table.  I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @roryap what happens when you add a new table to the diagram

Comment: Ah, I was incorrect.  I didn't see that it had added the blank column to the end when I changed the view to "Standard".  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @roryap you can also change the default view by using menu bar Table Designer -> Table View -> Modify Custom -> Save As Default

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: User right click on table

[image: User right click on table]

Step 2: User left click on "Standard (menu item)"

[image: User left click on "Standard (menu item)"]

Step 3: User left click

[image: User left click]

Step 4: User keyboard input to enter new column

[image: User keyboard input to enter new column]

Thank You